# Cant store rgba Values with local storage JS

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Cant store rgba Values with local storage. Either that or I have made a mistake. Were dealing with a few things here.

In my Js file I have stored a color picker RGBA value as a string and stored it as seen below.

```js
pickr.on('change', (color, source, instance) => {
    
  const rgbaColor = color.toRGBA().toString();
  console.log(rgbaColor)
  localStorage.setItem("C1",rgbaColor);
 
})
```

Then I have a separate Js file with this function.

```
function colors(){
  document.querySelector('teamOne').style.background = localStorage.getItem("C1");
}
```

And Im trying to change the background color of a div in my css file. (im using scss btw)

```
#teamOne {
  width: 50%;  
}
```

I know that the color picker is working but the rest of the code wont. If someone could help that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: object.style.background-color: '${yourRGBA}'; have you tried this ?

Comment: const rgbaColor = color.toRGBA().toString();
console.log(rgbaColor) what does this log ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Should be:

`document.getElementById('teamOne').style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem('C1');`